# Unable to load a CLR UDT in Sql Server using CREATE TYPE

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlclr, user-defined-types

I created a UDT using C# and compiled it using .NETFW 2.0. I added it to the database successfully, and can see it when I do "select * from sys.assemblies"

I am now trying to consume the UDT defined in the assembly as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.SourceLocation
EXTERNAL NAME MyAssembly.[example.com.SourceLocation];
```

However, when I do this, I am getting an error as follows:

> Msg 6244, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The size (0) for
>   "MyAssembly.example.com.SourceLocation" is not in the valid range.
>   Size must be -1 or a number between 1 and 8000.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I can see the type when I run ildasm.exe.

I added the assembly using the command line. I am not using a VS Database project for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the source file? 
Check the `MaxByteSize` attribute? 
If it is not there then add it or change the value e.g.

```
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedType(Format.UserDefined, 
IsByteOrdered = true, MaxByteSize = 32)]
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public struct Currency : INullable, IComparable, IBinarySerialize
{
```

Comment: Thanks russell. That worked for me. In addition to your code, I had to change the MaxByteSize to -1 because I was storing big strings.